# Как заменить значения в xls без повторного экспорта данных в файл?

Tags: php, xls

Существует простой механизм: загружается файл на сервер, через phpexcel данные считываются в массив, далее по шаблону определенные значения в каждой ячейке(массиве) меняются, экспортируется новый массив в CSV и выдается ссылка на его скачивание.

Плюс : Просто

Минус:  Стили документа  форматируются, больше нет закрышенных ячеек, отсутствуют объединения

Есть ли способ считывать значения ячеек, но при этом сразу же записывать изменения в файл?

Comment: Конечно можно. Я не понимаю, в чем проблема? Сначала считываете ячейку, если устраивает значение - переходите дальше, если нет записываете в ячейку новое значение. Вы не знаете функций, с помощью которых писать? Можете приложить свой код, начиная от чтения файла?

Comment: При этом все стили сохранятся?

Comment: Да, должны, почему нет?

Comment: И обьединенные ячейки сохранятся? Дело в том, что я нашел в спецификации только метод toarray()  им я и считываю файл. С живой подменой данных ничего не встретил. И да, файлы всегда разные, тоесть определенной структуры у них нет.